# Where is the 'choco' command after a fresh install?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I installed Chocolatey and it works fine in the command prompt (`cmd.exe`). 
But, I'm lazy and want to call it from PowerShell. But, the command `choco` is not recognized in PowerShell. I get something like

> CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn, i find it: I had to restart the powershell after installing chocolatey.

Comment: Yes, this is working as expected.  After installing Chocolatey, a number of modules have been loaded, which need to be loaded into the current session.  This is done by closing and re-opening the shell.

Comment: You found a long pain with respect to Windows and shells. Windows just doesn't notify shells of path updates. :/